# How to process a Shopify GraphQL Bulk Request and download the response?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, fetch, shopify, bulk

I'm very new to javascript and graphQL in general. I've done my best to do my own research but now it's getting a bit more complicated and I'm a little lost.

I'm building an app for Shopify (React/Node) where it basically queries all my store's unfulfilled orders, and retrieves all the items in these orders. I'm only looking for one type of item, and it's coffee -- we roast it, so we need to know the total weights for all our coffee products. It looks a little something like this with a plain graphQL query:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCF0Z.png)

I exceed the limits for a plain query though, so I need to make a bulk query request. I've managed poll a bulk query fine and retrieve the data in the console, but this is something I have to actively call within the app - I need to data to be there ready for when my app loads, and then I need the data to be there and manageable so I can map it in the same way I did my plain query... and for the life of me I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated, I'm not expecting anyone to do it entirely for me, but I really barely just grasped how to do a .post request. I've only really been pursuing this a month or so now.

I'm trying to get these queries here:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const BULK_OP = gql`
mutation {
  bulkOperationRunQuery(
    query:"""
    {
      orders(reverse:true, query: "fulfillment_status:unshipped AND status:open") {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            name
            lineItems {
              edges {
                node {
                  quantity
                  name
                  product {
                    productType
                    metafield(namespace: "global", key:"SO_num") {
                      value
                    }
                  }
                  variant {
                    weight
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      collections(first: 1, query: "id:260752932934") {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            products(first: 3, sortKey: BEST_SELLING) {
              edges {
                node {
                  title
                  metafield(namespace: "global", key: "SO_num") {
                    value
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
"""
 ) {
   bulkOperation {
     id
     status
   }
   userErrors {
     field
     message
   }
 }
}
`;

const CHECK_BULK = gql`
  query {
    currentBulkOperation {
      id
      status
      errorCode
      createdAt
      completedAt
      objectCount
      fileSize
      url
      partialDataUrl
    }
  }
`;


export { BULK_OP, CHECK_BULK }
```

I would post more of my code, but at this point I feel like most of it will be need to be redone on the basis of what I have to actually do to get this data before the app loads.

Any help would be appreciated, even a point in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/

Comment: @xadm I have referred to the docs, like I said I've successfully managed to create queries, and bulk queries - I was apprehensive to follow these docs too closely because they don't seem to even mention the bulk requests that Shopify supports? But my question was more about how to submit a bulk query and receive the data in the background while the app loads. Is that in here and I'm just being thick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bulk operations are designed for long-running processing.

**It's just a chain of data-flow** formed using **separate requests**.

Example for Apollo client (see docs for option details):

- `useMutation` to 'send' bulk - returns bulk `id`;
- `useQuery` to check processing state ... you can use `polling` option to automatic re-querying (use `network-only` fetch policy) ... and `skip` to stop after finished - returns `status`, `url`, `partialDataUrl`;
- when a bulk data ready, just fetch (use `axios`/`fetch`/whatever) to download prepared data [probably json] file from `url` (provided with query response) - the bulk response;
- use your [json decoded] data in component;

**Hint**: run mutation (on demand, from [some onClick] event handler) in separate component to not mix send/receive operations ... you can store/save bulk `id` [and processing state] in localStorage to be available on refresh

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm on the right track - think I was staring too long at the wrong things and this helped me reconfigure my brain a little.

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example or a link to one? I've read through ample documentation but can't seem to actually find an example in reactjs. I can execute the bulk operation, then in the onCompleted callback I get the gid:// link but no idea how to use that